# Set JAVA_HOME path for hadoop with Linux

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new with Linux, and I am trying to install and set Hadoop framework on my computer but I have some problems :

1) I have installed java 8 on my computer but when I put java -version in my shell it answers :

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

I was expecting a : java version "1.8.0_201" somewhere

2) In the `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` file I have set JAVA_HOME to :

```
"/usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_201"
```

But when I am in my hadoop directory and I put `./bin/hadoop` it answers :

```
  /home/kostia/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: 
ligne 54 : export: « /usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_201 » : identifiant non valable  
    ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do You set it in hadoop config? Could you please send exact line.

Comment: I have tried several things :

Comment: export JAVA_HOME= "/home/kostia/java/jdk1.8.0_201"

Comment: export JAVA_HOME= "/usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_201"

Comment: Could you try it without quotes?  export JAVA_HOME= /usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: export JAVA_HOME= "/usr/bin/java/"

Comment: It gives me the same answer :(

Comment: What does  echo $JAVA_HOME return?

Comment: I Found itb !!!

Comment: I had to write JAVA_HOME=/usr without space beween "=" and "/"

Comment: and $JAVA_HOME returns /bin/java thanks a lot

Comment: `which java` is a nice command & please see also: [How do I add environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58814/707903)